# Not rounded beamer blocks

Tags: beamer, environments

I want my blocks to be not rounded. I added this like to my style but without any success.

```
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded=false, shadow=true]
```

How to make not rounded boxes in beamer?

Edit:

I am using this theming in `ddbeamer.sty`:

```
\usetheme{Madrid}                                                                                                              
\useinnertheme{rectangles}                                                                                                     
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}                                                                                               
\usecolortheme{structure}                                                                                                      
\usepackage{times}
```

Using `\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default,shadow=true]` also does not work.

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[english,10pt,blackandwhite,compress]{beamer}                                                                    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                                                                    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                                                                       
\usepackage{xcolor}                                                                                                            
\usepackage{babel}                                                                                                             
\usepackage{ddbeamer}                                                                                                          
\usepackage{lmodern}                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Hi}
      Bye
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Which theme do you use? Could you provide a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Unfortunately `\usecolortheme{structure}` does not work for me, so I could only try the rest)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\usecolortheme{structure}
\usepackage{times} 

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{block}{Block 1: Guguck}
        Hallo du da, im Radio!
    \end{block}

    \begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=1.02\textwidth]

        \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{Block 2a: Guguck und eine laengere Ueberschrift}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item b
                    \item c
                \end{itemize}
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{Block 2b: Guguck}
                Hallo du da, im Radio!
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Ok so now I know what was the problem. You probably cannot use shadow=true and default (or rounded = false) together. Thank you for directing me to this. Btw. structure still works for me.