# rounded and not rounded blocks

Tags: beamer, block, rounded-corners

I would like to know if it is possible to have to different kinds of blocks and how to do it in beamer.

As an example, one rounded for examples and one not rounded for theorems.

Is it possible to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes, it is certainly possible, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132380/121799). And for the theorems see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347274/121799). samcarter is probably hibernating, err, sleeping now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly combined from [this nice answer by samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347274/121799) and [this nice answer by samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132380/121799). Only improvement: load the `tikzmarmots` package (by samcarter).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\usepackage{tikzmarmots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg}

\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=example text,fg=example text.fg,bg=example text.fg!20!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.bg!50!bg}

\addtobeamertemplate{proof begin}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=red!50!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=red, bg=red!30!white}
    \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]
}{}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{theorem}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=orange!50!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=orange, bg=orange!30!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{theorem}{
 \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
 \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=pink!50!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=pink, bg=pink!30!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{
 \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
 \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{definition}[Marmot]
        A marmot is a \emph{being}.
    \end{definition}

    \begin{theorem}[My theorem]
        The colder the winter, the longer the hibernation time. 
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}[My proof]
        $t_\mathrm{hibernate}\propto T^\alpha$ with $\alpha<0$.
    \end{proof}
    \begin{example}[My example]
        \tikz{\marmot[teeth,whiskers,blush]}
    \end{example}

    \begin{block}{My block}
        A block.
    \end{block}    

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]